# cleaning JSON - removing unnecessary properties with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a JSON file that is approximately 1 MB (menu.json). There are a lot of properties within it that I am hoping to remove.

I have one text file: Strings.txt - this contains names of properties that are note needed in the JSON

I am trying to iterate through my JSON file line by line. If a line contains a string found in strings.txt, I want to remove that line.

Here is my code:

```
tmp = File.open('clean.json', 'w')

File.open('menu.json') do |json|
  File.open('strings.txt') do |x|
      tmp.puts json.each_line unless json.include? x
  end
end
```

The result that is written to clean.json is #`<Enumerator:0x0077ff36b04b468>`

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? This is my first Ruby script.

Contents of `strings.txt`:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

It turns out Item1, Item2 or Item3 are all being read as \\"Item1\\"

I have to figure out why this is happening and how to handle it.

Comment: What is in the `menu.json` and `strings.txt`. And what is the expected result?

Comment: strings.txt contains a property name followed by a carriage return. menu.json is the 1MB json file that I would like to have the lines deleted containing the property names in strings.txt

Comment: Well, that tells me nothing (almost). Trim down your files and paste in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`each_line` without a block returns an enumerator, which is what you're writing to your output file. What you want is something more like this:

```
tmp = File.open('clean.json', 'w')

File.open('menu.json') do |json|
  File.open('strings.txt') do |x|
    json.each_line { |line| tmp.puts(line) unless line.include?(x) }
  end
end
tmp.close
```

This is obviously pretty expensive since it will go through all of `menu.json` exactly as many times as `strings.txt` has lines.

Comment: For some reason, all that is being written to clean.json is [ . strings.txt only contains a string on each line so I am currently unsure why this is happening.

Comment: Given your expert advice as to the expensive nature of this, I would like to move forward with adifferent pattern. How would you solve this problem? Using bash to loop sed?

Comment: Try to use `jq`: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ Also I'm afraid I can't help you more with your Ruby implementation unless we see at least a few lines of `strings.txt` and and all of `menu.json`.